# GitLab hangs when merging

Tags: gitlab

When I click on the button **Accept Merge Request** merging is hangs, but requests are sent to the server.

[image]

**This Apache log:**

[image]

**This version Gitlab:**

[image]

**This production.log:**

[image]

**This githost.log:**

[image]

Comment: Have you find the solution for this?